# Why C adds weird characters to my char array?

Tags: c, character

I'm working on a hangman project, and as you can see in my code, it adds some weird characters to my strings in some case. Not always, but most of the time. (for ex.: MOUSE =>  MOUSE@ 
Due to I can't do string comparison, and it's ugly too. Any solutions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char animals [8][20] = {"LION" ,"GIRAFFE","OCTOPUS", "RHINOCEROS","CENTIPEDE",  "ELEPHANT", "MOUSE", "DOG"};
int i ;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int choose;
    choose = rand()% 7;
    int length;
    printf("%s", animals[choose]);
    length = strlen(animals[choose]);
    char result[length];

    for(i=0; i< length;i++) {
        result[i] = '_' ;
    }

  printf("%s", result);

  while(1) {
    printf("\nEnter guess char!:  ") ;
    char guess ;
    scanf(" %c", &guess) ;
    guess = toupper(guess) ;
    hangman(guess, result, animals[choose], length ) ;
  }

  return 0;
}

void hangman (char guess, char result[], char word[], int length ){
    for(i=0; i< length; i++) {
        if(guess == word[i]) {
            result[i] = guess ;
    }
  }

  printf("%s", result) ;

  if(strcmp(result, word)== 0 ){
    printf("gratulation!") ;
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW `choose = rand()% 7 ;` --> `choose = rand()% 8 ;`

Comment: Don't you get any warnings?! You didn't include `<time.h>` therefore the very first line in your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Indentation/spacing bad. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

strlen(animals[choose]) doesn't include the '\0' NUL terminating character in the string so you need to add one to length when creating result.  You also need to null terminate result like this;

```
char result[length+1];
result[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I just realized that.  not used to using them.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I think you mean

```
choose = rand() % 8;
                 ^^^
```

because the array animals is declared like

```
char animals [8][20] = /*...*/;
             ^^^
```

This format specifier `"%s"` used in this call

```
printf("%s", result) ;
```

is designed to output string with terminating zero. However the character array `result` does not contain a string.

You could write

```
char result[length + 1] ;
for(i=0; i < length;i++) {
result[i] = '_' ;
}
result[i] = '\0';
```